# Creating default object from empty value php 5,5

Tags: php, stdclass

I try to create new stdClass but still nothing and this code make an error:
Warning: Creating default object from empty value.

```
function __construct($params) {
    parent::__construct($params);
    //$this -> view -> controller = null;
    $this -> view -> controller = new stdClass(); // <-- HERE IS ERROR 
    $this -> view -> controller = 'Index';

    require_once 'models/_index_model.php';
    $this -> model = new Index_model();

    $action = 'News';
    if(isset($params[1])){ $action = ucfirst($params[1]); }

    $this->date = 'Today';
    if(isset($params[2])) $this->date = ucfirst($params[2]);

    $this->$action($this->date);
}
```

Comment: what is $this? which method variable refers to it? does it have a view attribute?

Comment: please add this code to your question. it's really hard to follow code that way.

Comment: creating objects is not so difficult. 
there are two steps: create an object instance, and set attributes to it (for `stdClass`). look up this code: http://codepad.org/8AZAjGKY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that there's no value for the variable `$view`

I'm not sure what you'd like to achieve, but the code should work if you implement it like in the following example:

```
function __construct($params) {
    parent::__construct($params);

    $this -> view = new stdClass(); // create a new stdClass object
    $this -> view -> controller = 'Index'; // assign the controller value

    // ... and so on
}
```

So the main problem here, is that the variable `$view` was not declared, or its value is not an object.

Feel free to ask in the comment section if there are more questions